# comparing two filenames using a logical AND

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
mainFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'select all excel files in this folder
fname = Dir(FPath & "\*.xls")

'go through all excel files in this folder
Do While fname <> ""
    If (fname <> mainFile & fname <> uploadFile) Then
        Debug.Print (mainFile & ":" & uploadFile & ":" & fname)
```

For some reason, the fname <> mainFile isn't preventing it from entering the loop, and I get the following from the Debug.Print statement:
     functions.xls:UPLOADME.xls:functions.xls

And then the code just stops executing...no error...just nothing (I have a Debug.Print after the loop that is ignored along with everything else)

Am I not comparing them correctly?

Comment: Sigh...I am an idiot...it should be:
    fname <> mainFile AND fname <> uploadFile

Sorry....

Comment: You might like to look at `ActiveWorkbook.FullName`

Comment: @Irfanjamal  No! Sometimes it just takes the act of asking for help to solve one's own problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be: `fname <> mainFile And fname <> uploadFile`

In VBA, the `&` operator is used to concatenate strings, not to perform a logical AND... "And" is the operator I was looking for.